# ExpressJS: require multiple files with app.use()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

**Routing**:

```
app.use('/cms/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/cms/schools/', require('./routes/schools.js'));
```

**Routes**:

```
/cms/
/cms/schools/
/cms/schools/:schoolId/classes/:classId
```

**Goal**: I'd like to split `./routes/schools.js` into two files: `schools.js` and `schools_classes.js`, to keep a better overview.

**Problem**: I'd like to keep the prefixed path `/cms/schools/`, but don't know how to split it correctly.

How can I structure the files to reach the desired goal? 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**: 
I tried the following, which is not working (duplicated route prefix):

```
app.use('/cms/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/cms/schools/', require('./routes/schools.js'));
app.use('/cms/schools/', require('./routes/schools_classes.js'));
```

Comment: Why are you using `required()` with a `d`?

Comment: @jfriend00 It was a typo (I didn't copy the code), thank you.

Comment: If you want to split your module in two, that's fine, but only of the split modules should export the route handler and that's the only module that you `require()`.  You can `require()` in the other one from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do It using the express router:

Routes:

```
const schoolsRouter = require('./routes/schools');
app.use('/cms/schools', schoolsRouter)
```

./routes/schools/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/',require('./schools _controller.js'));
router.use('/:schoolId/classes/:classId', require ('./schools_classes_controller.js'));

module.exports = router;
```

You can check the entire router docs here: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router